# How to disable Woocommerce login redirect if on Checkout Page

Tags: woocommerce

I have some code in my WordPress functions.php file to do a redirect after a successful woocommerce login. It works great, but I'm wondering how I can disable that redirect from running on the checkout page?

If a user logs into their account while on the checkout page they are getting redirected off the checkout page just before they have the chance to fill in their credit card data which isn't a great experience.

According to https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/ conditional query tags like is_checkout() won't work in the functions.php file because You can only use conditional query tags after the posts_selection action hook in WordPress. And, unfortunately, apparently the functions.php file gets run before that.

What's my best option to solve this?

Here's the code I currently have running (the one I want to disable on checkout page):

```
function woo_login_redirect( $redirect_to ) {
    $redirect_to = get_permalink(70241);
    return $redirect_to;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_login_redirect', 'woo_login_redirect');
```

This is me trying to avoid the redirect if on checkout page (it doesn't work. It just redirects to post id 70241):

```
function woo_login_redirect( $redirect_to ) {
  if (is_checkout()){
    $redirect_to = '#'; 
  } else {
    $redirect_to = get_permalink(70241);
  } 
  return $redirect_to;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_login_redirect', 'woo_login_redirect');
```